# Android NDK > 18 is not building module in Fedora 36 (incompatible with elf32-i386 error)

Tags: linux, gradle, android-ndk, clang, fedora

### Issue

I'm building an Android module for a mobile app framework using [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) 36 (Linux kernel 5.19.12-200.fc36.x86_64). Everything works fine when I use [NDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_NDK) 18.1.5063045.

I've tested [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro) 22.0.3 and have the same issue. OS X works fine!

As soon as I use a more recent version, e.g., 21.4.7075529, I end up with the following error:

```
[ERROR] [GRADLE]
[ERROR] [GRADLE] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] [GRADLE]
[ERROR] [GRADLE] * What went wrong:
[ERROR] [GRADLE] Execution failed for task ':module:buildNdkBuildRelease'.
[ERROR] [GRADLE] > Build command failed.
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   Error while executing process /home/user/tools/android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/src/main/jni/Android.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_OUT=/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/lib APP_CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++14 APP_STL:=c++_shared -j20 --output-sync=none ti.module}
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   Android NDK: WARNING:/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/src/main/jni/Android.mk:ti.module: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lkroll-v8
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   Android NDK:     current module
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: ti.module <= ti.module.CameraViewProxy.cpp
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: ti.module <= ti.module.TiCameraxModule.cpp
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   [armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: ti.module <= TiModuleBootstrap.cpp
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libti.module.so
[ERROR] [GRADLE]
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/tools/android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/19/crtbegin_so.o is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ti.module/__/__/__/build/ti-generated/jni/ti.module.CameraViewProxy.o is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ti.module/__/__/__/build/ti-generated/jni/ti.module.TiCameraxModule.o is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/ti.module/__/__/__/build/ti-generated/jni/TiModuleBootstrap.o is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/tools/android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/19/liblog.so is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/11.1.1.GA/android/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libkroll-v8.so is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   ld: error: /home/user/tools/android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi/19/crtend_so.o is incompatible with elf32-i386
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[ERROR] [GRADLE]   make: *** [/home/user/tools/android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/build/core/build-binary.mk:657: /home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libti.module.so] Fehler 1
[ERROR] [GRADLE]
```

The `ndk-build` command with its parameters is:

```
/home/user/tools/android-sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/ndk-build
  NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
  APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/src/main/jni/Android.mk
  APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
  NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a
  NDK_DEBUG=0
  APP_PLATFORM=android-19
  NDK_OUT=/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/obj
  NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/user/dev/ti.module/android/build/module/build/intermediates/cxx/Release/18714c4q/lib
  APP_CPPFLAGS+=-std=c++14
  APP_STL:=c++_shared
  -j20
  --output-sync=none
  ti.module
```

**Android.mk** ([source in repository](https://github.com/tidev/titanium_mobile/blob/b3256959bf84a6fb2e3e86554cdc0867f0d533c3/android/templates/module/generated/Android.mk))

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ti.module

# Allow non-constant format strings in functions like printf(), sprintf(), etc.
LOCAL_DISABLE_FORMAT_STRING_CHECKS=true

TI_SDK_DIR = /home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/11.1.1.GA/android
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g "-I$(TI_SDK_DIR)/native/include"
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-conversion-null -Wno-format-security -Wno-format -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-result -Wno-deprecated-register
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -ldl -llog -L$(TARGET_OUT) "-L$(TI_SDK_DIR)/native/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)" -lkroll-v8

ABS_SRC_FILES := \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp) \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../build/ti-generated/jni/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%,%,$(ABS_SRC_FILES))

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

[Build.gradle file in repo](https://github.com/tidev/titanium_mobile/blob/b3256959bf84a6fb2e3e86554cdc0867f0d533c3/android/templates/module/generated/build.gradle)

### Question

Is there anything I'll need to change/install on my Fedora machine in order to use NDK > 18 so it doesn't stop with this error:

> This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies...

##### Current workaround

Since it works with NDK 18 I continue to use NDK 18 and link the NDK 21 folder to my NDK 18 folder.

### How to test

Since it is a module for a mobile framework you'll need to install the framework itself:

- install Titanium CLI `sudo npm i -g titanium`
- install SDK `ti sdk install latest`
- clone a module repo like https://github.com/tidev/ti.map
- go into the ti.map/android folder and run `ti build -p android -b`

### What I've tested

I've changed the *Android.mk* file to use

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TI_SDK_DIR)/native/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libkroll-v8.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Which builds the module, but it doesn't build/include the `jni/arm*` and `jni/x86*` folders with a `.so` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you don't need to install `i686` libraries anymore to work with NDK/Android under linux. I've tested it with other developers in fresh linux distributions and they worked.

So in case you want to run NDK >18 you **don't install** these tools

```
for Ubuntu 13.10 and beyond     sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5\
                                libstdc++6:i386
for Fedora                      su -c 'yum install libstdc++.i686\
                                ncurses-libs.i686 zlib.i686'
```

only needed for NDK <=18!

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue and it solved by updating the `Android.mk` file.

So, Update your Android.mk file to use `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` or `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` instead of listing libraries directly in the linker flags.

Also, see if you have the necessary dependencies installed on your Fedora machine. The newer NDK 18.1 might need additional libraries or packages to be installed.

Comment: Can you give an example for `to use LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead of listing libraries directly in the linker flags.` please? Not sure about the dependencies as the NDK is installed through Studio and not with Fedora. I'll look into that

Comment: Hi, Sreeram Nair.  

Most or all of your last 11 answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Many also have comments indicating that they are wrong in some respect. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.